# Displaying KMZ file + my location in Android Google Maps application?

Tags: android, kmz

I don't know anything about GIS.

Someone sent me a GPX file that I converted into a KMZ file so it's displayed in Google Maps.

It works fine when viewed in a browser, but I'd like to display it in the dedicated Maps application in Android so I can view the KMZ route and my current location at the same time so I don't stray away from the planned route when going for a ride.

However, Maps doesn't like pasting the URL with the KMZ file.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way to see both a KMZ route and the current location?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround to do this.
You can import your kmz file from your pc using the classic (legacy) "import with classic google maps" link on google maps. This link allow you to import kmz/kmz files in new maps engine format with a limit of 3MB.

Now you can download mapsEngine app for android and open the link to the new converted file.

Answer (score -1):

I usually do it like this:

1. Use your PC to go to google maps
2. click "my places" and click "make map"
3. click on import and select the kmz file
4. give the map a title and save it
5. now use your android and open the google maps app
6. click on the layers symbol at the top
7. open "my maps" and open the specific map

Answer (score -1):

You can use [OSMNavigator](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/). 
It displays the current GPS location, and can load/display a KML or KMZ file.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to view a KMZ file with my location offline (in airplane mode) using by uploading the file to shared internal storage, installing Google Earth for Android and installing [KMLZ to Earth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.wrightrocket.kmlkmz&hl=en).  Find the file using KMLZ to Earth and it will open in Google Earth and will show your location.