# Looking for a good solution to have GPS position on KMZ files on Android platform

Tags: gps, google-earth, android, kmz, google-maps-engine

I'm looking for the best solution / app on the android platform to show my GPS position over a KMZ file, possibly offline.
Here is what I've tried to do:

1. Google Earth Android app

I downloaded KMLZ to Earth app and Google Earth app. Now I can open my KMZ files stored in a Google Drive with Google Earth, but GPS position seems to be not accurate. Also KMZ file doesn't look very well.

2. Maps Engine Android app

I manage in converting my KMZ file to Google MapsEngine. You can find how to looking at my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58664/displaying-kmz-file-my-location-in-android-google-maps-application/99979#99979). Now the GPS position is ok, vector drawing is ok too, but I need to be always online.

3. Other apps

I've also tried many KMZ viewer, but got some problems opening my files on most of them, and none of these apps seems to be very good.

Can anybody suggest a better solution/app?